# Origin of the word ''захолустье''

Tags: этимология

What is the etymological origin of the word ''захолустье''?

For me, the origin of this word is a big mystery of the Russian language.

In modern Russian, this word means ''a remote place, a place that remains unaffected by new events, progress, ideas, etc.''

Vasmer's etymological dictionary, which is considered to be the most complete and credible Russian etymological dictionary, says the following about the origin of this word:

> **захолу́стье** До сих пор не получило удовлетворительного объяснения.
>   Сравнивали за- и ст.-слав. халѫга «изгородь», словен. halóga
>   «кустарник, морская трава» (Маценауэр, LF 7, 217; Преобр. I, 243;
>   Горяев, ЭС 114), но в таком случае ожидалось бы *захалужье. Влияние
>   слова холосто́й (Преобр.) невероятно. Неудовлетворительно также
>   сравнение с холо́п, холу́й у Соболевского (ЖМНП, 1886, сент., стр.
>   146). Калима («Neuphil. Мitt.», 1951, стр. 167 и сл.) пытается
>   произвести захолустье из *захолостье от холост, что затруднительно
>   фонетически. [Сближение с холудина, хлуд см. у Трубачева (ZfS, 4,
>   1959, стр. 84). Иначе см. Львов, «Этим. исследования по русск. языку»,
>   I, М., 1960, стр. 32. — Т.]

As you see, the dictionary says that no satisfactory etymological explanation has been found.

The same thing is also said in another highly reputable etymological dictionary, Preobrazhensky's dictionary.

An interesting hypothesis is put forward in the Internet: The word is of Mongolian origin. In modern Mongolian, the expression ''зах улс'' means or can be interpreted as ''a distant country,'' with ''зах'' meaning ''edge'' and ''улс'' meaning ''country.'' The similarity in the meaning and pronunciation is striking, and the hypothesis seems plausible in view of the fact that Russia was a vassal state of the Mongol Empire.

Intrigued, I did some research, and the facts found by me support the hypothesis. First, I verified in Google Translator as well as in a Mongolian dictionary that in modern Mongolian, ''зах улс'' can indeed be interpreted as a ''distant country.'' Second, the Mongolian etymological dictionary by Rajki says that the word ''улс'' originated from the Old Mongolian word ''ulus'', which can explain why it is ''захолустье,'' not ''захулстье.'' Third, in modern Kalmyk, which belongs to Mongolic languages, Russian federal subjects are called ''зах улс'' - for example, Stavropol Krai is called ''Ставрополин зах улс.''

I think that on this forum, there are many experts and fans of the Russian language, and some of them may be able to shed some light on the mystery.

Is this word, which sounds so Russian, in fact a trace of the Mongol invasion?

Comment: sounds very probable, all the more so that this would by far not be a single loan word assimilated into Russian language [during the Golden Horde times](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Тюркизмы_в_русском_языке#Период_Золотой_Орды) or under its influence

Comment: so you basically found out that scientists don't know and encourage amateurs to speak out? )))

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка - mongolian and turkic were quite different even back then, also there's no words starting with z in that least - and there's a reason for this).

Comment: @shabunc i'm not aware of the exact connection between Turkic influence on Russian and Mongolian conquest, but the fact that some such borrowings harken back specifically to this period does suggest existence of a connection, as far as i know Tartars were a part of Mongolian tribes at the time of the conquest (not without reason they're called **монголо-татары** in the historiography, at least of the Soviet period) and Tartars' native language may have been Turkic back then as well

Comment: the word [**улус**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Улус) in a sense of **locality** is also known unrelated to the etymology of **захолустье**

Comment: shabunc (''so you basically found out that scientists don't know and encourage amateurs to speak out?''), yes :) I wonder how much time per word Vasmer and Preobrazhensky spent when they compiled their etymological dictionaries, given the large number of words these dictionaries contain. Were these guys able to conduct a thorough investigation of the origin of each and every word, especially given the absence of the Internet at that time? :) In general, etymological dictionaries are known to contain inaccuracies and errors.

Answer (score 5):

I am an amateur an have no right to make assumptions somewhere where scientists (who dedicated years studying some specific issues) failed. However I'm bold enough to say that the Mongolian origin in this particular case is highly, highly unlikely for some reasons from which one of most important one - for Slavic languages prefix `за-` (which is actually a merged preposition `[за][1]`) is very well known for forming  words of similar meaning.

For instance, in Polish there's `zadupie` which any Russian speaker will recognize as `зажопье`. "Залесье", "заграница", "запад" are other examples. This fact per se casts some doubts that some foreign phrase started with `зах` was used in similar form. That happens though! - my favorite example is word `изъян` which is actually [of a Persian origin](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%B8/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%BD) borrowed through Turkic - originally it was `ziyan`. It is believed that Russian verb `изъять` influenced it's formation and now it feels like a very, very Russian word.

Other thing to consider - as far as I understand in Mongolian there's no [z] sound at all but rather a form of affricate [d͡z] for which Russian letter "з" stands (don't get fooled by Mongolian Cyrillic - pronunciation can be  quite [different](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8671/how-similar-are-mongolian-cyrillic-and-russian-cyrillic)). In Middle Mongolian even this affricate [was non-existent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Mongol_language). So to make any claims of this kind we should check how similar phrase might sound in Middle Mongolian - language tend to change.

Once again - I don't know. My counter-arguments easily can be as amateurish as your arguments. However from what I know about, from what I've read - well, let me put it this way - we still need to take into consideration a lot of additional data to back this theory.

Comment: Indeed. I have even better theory - the old Russian word comes from modern English `the hollow star` (with slightly distorted ending). That is: Folk etymology on the march.

Comment: a counter-argument based on the degree of likelihood derived from the fact of existence of a similarly sounding Russian pronoun is unconvincing, as you yourself admit, words tend to naturalize in the borrowing language to sound quite different from the source language, especially when they belong to different families, another example is [Тмутаракань](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Тмутаракань)

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка first thing we should do - is to verify how this was pronounced in Middle Mongolian - this is starting point as to me.

Comment: instead of *pronoun* i meant to write *preposition*

Comment: @seven-phases-max "the old Russian word comes from modern English the hollow star" - oh cmon, where is ''za-'' and how are the meanings related? :) To be serious, the most striking fact for me is that in modern Kalmyk, Stavropol Krai is "Ставрополин зах улс" - you can simply google this exact phrase to check. Altai Krai is "Алтагин зах улс." And so on.

Comment: @shabunc (''first thing we should do - is to verify how this was pronounced in Middle Mongolian'') The Old Mongolian version of ''зах'' is ''diqa,'' according to the Mongolian etymological dictionary by Rajki. I see that all modern Mongolian words starting with ''з'' start with ''d'' in the Old Mongolian. For example, the Old Mongolian version of the word ''захиа'' (a letter) is ''dikiyan.'' The Old Mongolian version of ''улс'' is ''ulus,'' so ''зах улс'' must have been ''diqa ulus.''

Comment: @Sandra well, there's also non-zero probability that it was some of Mongolian languages  or dialects (it depends on how to count) -  may be it's a later borrowing from I dunno - Kalmyk or Buryat. Still not enough data to claim this.

Comment: @shabunc Yes, I just did additional research and found a hypothesis saying that ''захолустье'' was taken from Kalmyk, where it originally sounded ''заха улус.'' Kalmyks separated from Mongols long after the Mongol invasion of Rus and migrated to where they (Kalmyks) live now, so if the hypothesis is true, then the word is not a trace of the Mongol invasion, although still of Mongolic origin.

Comment: @Sandra The main problem is that the whole thing is based on the totally up-side-down method if compared to the proper scientific methods. I.e. first you find a pretty much random language that have similarly sounding words and having approximately related meaning and then you try to find/invent "a story" (when and where it could be borrowed) behind  that.

Comment: @Sandra It *is* possible it's a borrowing from Kalmyk (or whatever), but the way you came to it makes the hypothesis absolutely unvaluable (not very different from the ["comic" works of Zadornov](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Задорнов,_Михаил_Николаевич#Этимология) who could derive every word of any language from the modern Russian). This is just not how these things work.
I'm pretty sure I'd be able to do the same for potentially Iranian, Turkic, Romanian, Lithuanian, Finnish. Germanic etc. etc. sources of "захолустье" (if only I'd be familiar with any of them :).

Comment: And because of that the starting point should always be *when* and *where* a word came to use (and then all the usual details like the state of the language(s) then and there, etc. etc.; with a search for potential sources for the borrowing being *the last step*). And never up-side-down like: I know Frisian so if I notice some similarly sounding things between Frisian and Zulu I start to search for "stories" about possible borrowing in either direction.

Comment: @Sandra *oh cmon, where is ''za-'' and how are the meanings related?* - "za" is obviously "the" if you speak with an awful accent. How related? It could be a name of the first English trade ship that landed in Novgorodian lands ;)
*striking fact for me is that Stavropol Krai is "Ставрополин зах улс"* - So what? Some Irishman will find striking to hear "туда, блин" (it points to a certain "location" so it just "obviously" can't be unrelated to Dublin, can it? ;)

Comment: @seven-phases-max Sandra wrote that the suggestion of the Mongolic origin had been proposed on the Web, the method by which the author of the proposition has arrived at it is thus far unknown, therefore labeling it *an upside down method* or give it any other designation may be a little rash at the moment

Comment: @Баян Купи-ка Probably. I just assumed that since no other information except *modern* Kalmyk is given, it's one of the infinite "blog sources" where actual words of certain Mongol origin are mixed with "borrowings" like "Москва <- мушгаа",  "*уй <-  хуяг" and so on.

Comment: @seven-phases-max ("the starting point should always be when and where a word came to use"), well, I just did some additional research and found that Shaposhnikov's etymological dictionary says that the word ''захолустье'' was not used in the Russian language of the 15th-17th centuries and that the first mention of this word in a dictionary dates back to 1794. If this word is of Slavic origin, why was it not used before? Strikingly, the absorption of the Kalmyk Khanate by the Russian empire occurred in ~1660, just a century before the first mention of the word ''захолустье'' in a dictionary.

Comment: @Sandra words of Slavic origin come to existence and ceased from existence all the time - this is a never-ending process. However this is vert valuable information - it looks like that still this word being used later that Mongolian invasion happened.

Comment: @shabunc in view of the information that the word was not used until the 18th century I can more or less confidently rule out the possibility of this word being a direct trace of the Mongol invasion or the subsequent Mongol yoke, which was lifted in the 15th century. Maybe the word was taken from Kalmyk, and maybe it wasn't. I think the Kalmyk hypothesis deserves attention because of the striking similarity in the pronunciation and meaning as well as in the timing of the appearance of this word in the Russian language and the absorption of the Kalmyk Khanate by the Russian Empire.

Comment: @Sandra keep in mind that Kalmyks arrived to what is now European Russia at the end of XVI-th century

Answer (score 1):

I did some additional research and now will briefly summarise my findings (which I mostly already stated in the comments under Shabunc's answer):

(1) The Old Mongolian version of ''зах'' is ''diqa,'' according to the Mongolian etymological dictionary by Rajki. I see that all modern Mongolian words starting with ''з'' start with ''d'' in the Old Mongolian. For example, the Old Mongolian version of the word ''захиа'' (a letter) is ''dikiyan.'' The Old Mongolian version of ''улс'' is ''ulus,'' so ''зах улс'' must have been ''diqa ulus.'' Thus, the Russian word ''захолустье'' is phonetically far closer to the modern Mongolian and Kalmyk versions, ''зах улс,'' than to the Old Mongolian version.

(2) Shaposhnikov's etymological dictionary says that the word ''захолустье'' was not used in the Russian language of the 15th-17th centuries and that the first mention of this word in a dictionary dates back to 1794.

(3) In view of findings (1) and (2) above, I can more or less confidently rule out the possibility of this word being a direct trace of the Mongol invasion or the subsequent Mongol yoke, which was lifted in the 15th century.

(4) In the Internet, I found many articles saying that ''захолустье'' was taken from Kalmyk, where it originally sounded ''заха улус'' and meant ''distant/edge people/settlement.'' If this is true, then the word is still of Mongolic origin, as Kalmyk belongs to Mongolic languages. However, none of the articles I saw contains any proof to confirm the statement. They are about Kalmyks in general and mention the allegedly Kalmyk origin of the word ''захолустье'' merely as a side note.

(5) The absorption of the Kalmyk Khanate by the Russian Empire occurred in ~1660, a century before the first mention of the word ''захолустье'' in a dictionary, so the Kalmyk hypothesis cannot be refuted simply by considering timings. It could be refuted by timings if the word had been used in the Russian language before the interactions between the Russians and Kalmyks.

(6) Dal's dictionary, originally published in 1863, defines the word ''захолустье'' as follows:

> ЗАХОЛУСТЬЕ ср. глушь, глухое место; закоулок или малолюдная часть в
>   городе; чаща в лесу: отдаленное и малонаселенное, малопроезжее место;
>   затишье. Захолустник, житель глуши, захолустья. Захолюсток м. арх.
>   скрывище, убежище, приют, и пр. заливец, где укрываются суда.

The existence of the archaic word ''захолюсток'' (shelter) seems to favour the Slavic hypothesis of the origin of the word ''захолустье''. In the Kalmyk hypothesis, it is not easy to explain the existence and meaning of the word ''захолюсток,'' which was already considered archaic in 1863.

So it looks like the word was either somehow formed in the Russian language from another Russian word in the 18th century or, less likely, taken from Kalmyk in the 18th century. In any case the word is a not a direct trace of the Mongol invasion or the subsequent Mongol yoke.